# iOS Core Data : error when assigning a value to an attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode6

This is the MyApp.xcdatamodeld, very simple :

_[image]

And this the class associated with the entity :

```
class LogItem: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var itemText: String
    @NSManaged var itemRank: String

}
```

Now this is the code that causes the error :

```
let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("LogItem", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! LogItem
newItem.title = "the title of the item"
newItem.itemText = "je suis chérif"
newItem.itemRank = "2" // this line causes an error !
```

And finally the error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[MyApp.LogItem setItemRank:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155a8e30'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I cannot see an obvious error. Does the code run without problems if you remove that single line? Are you sure that you did not change the Core Data model (or created another version) after the `class LogItem` has been created?

Comment: I had modified the class LogItem after its creation. I cleaned the project and now it works ! So no error at all actually.

Answer (score 0):

When I work with core data objects I create the entity with the following line of code.

```
let logEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("LogItem", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
let newItem = LogItem(entity: logEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectCntext: self.managedObjectContext!)

newItem.title = "the title of the item"
newItem.itemText = "je suis chérif"
newItem.itemRank = "2"
```

Then save the context.